# Symlinks not recognized when pulled from git

Tags: linux, git, unix, symlink

I have a project in git, which when I symlinks down from git the first time, the symlinks do not work. From all I can see they are properly made symlinks. If I remove the symlinks and recreate them myself, git also sees them as Identical to the ones it has.

Is there a setting in Linux or Git that would prevent symlinks from working if they came form git?

The command used to create the symlinks:

```
ln -s /absolute/path/to/dest symlink-name
```

Some additional information

- Symlinks were originally created on a MacBook, but since git sees my newly created symlinks (on linux) as identical, I doubt this is the issue.
- When getting the symlinks for the first time, they do not work on linux, but on other Mac machines they do.
- After fixing the symlinks by deleting and recreating them, git sees them as identical and hench they are not overridden in future pulls.
- All symlinks are to .phar files.
- The linux machines are running Ubuntu 16.04 or Centos 7

Using `ls -lah` lists the symlinks as regular files:

```
-rw-rw-r--.  1 vagrant vagrant   28 Nov 13 09:01 dep
-rw-rw-r--.  1 vagrant vagrant   28 Nov 13 09:01 drupal
-rw-rw-r--.  1 vagrant vagrant   20 Nov 13 09:01 drush
-rw-rw-r--.  1 vagrant vagrant   32 Nov 13 09:01 drush.complete.sh
-rw-rw-r--.  1 vagrant vagrant   29 Nov 13 09:01 drush.launcher
-rw-rw-r--.  1 vagrant vagrant   24 Nov 13 09:01 drush.php
-rw-rw-r--.  1 vagrant vagrant   33 Nov 13 09:01 php-parse
-rw-rw-r--.  1 vagrant vagrant   26 Nov 13 09:01 phpunit
-rw-rw-r--.  1 vagrant vagrant   22 Nov 13 09:01 psysh
```

Whereas, if I manually remove and recreate the `dep` symlink, it shows up correctly. Git still sees this as identical and no changes were made.

```
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 vagrant vagrant   28 Nov 13 09:33 dep -> ../deployer/deployer/bin/dep
```

Changing the permissions form  `-rw-rw-r--` to `lrwxrwxrwx` on the broken symlinks, does not fix them either.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean they "do not work"?  How do they fail?  What does `ls` show?  Do they have any special characters?

Comment: @EdwardThomson I've edited the post to include such information, thanks for asking as I hadn't thought about providing that information.

Comment: Why do you write `\absolute\path`?  `\` is not a path separator on  Linux.

Comment: @JohnZwinck was just a path placeholder so I wouldn't need to type in the actual path, though that is negated quite a bit later on in my post, used `\\`` in the examply by mistake, will get fixed. (Actual symlink correctly uses `/`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your configuration files has turned *off* the `core.symlinks` setting.  To find out where this was set, run:

```
for location in global system local; do
    git config -l --$location |& grep -q symlinks && echo $location
done
```

This will output whether it is set in the global, system or local location.

The *global* location is typically `$HOME/.gitconfig`, the *system* location is typically `/etc/gitconfig`, and the *local* location is typically `.git/config` in the current repository.

Remove that line and Git should be able to create symlinks properly.

Comment: `show-origin` does not seem to be a valid option (using git 1.8.3.1)

Comment: Right, that's a newer setting.  I've updated with some shell that will enumerate the configuration locations.

Comment: I had it in my local config, it seems SourceTree automatically sets it to false on windows machines, but on mac the setting is never set.

Comment: Right - it should be set to `false` on Windows (and only on Windows).  This is a setting that's actually detected when you create a repository, and cached in the local repository configuration (so that you don't have to constantly detect the filesystem's capabilties).  You cannot share a working directory between two systems because of this (and other) configuration caches.